# Get case statuses using remote object model

Tags: case, remote-objects

I have some case statuses which belong to a certain process (process A) and others which belong to a different process, (process B). All of which are case processes.

How can I use remote object to get just those which belong to process A?

Comment: You mean support process?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in SFDC every support process is linked to a record type .So this means you will query for all cases falling under those record type only .

```js
var ct = new RemoteObjectModel.Case();
ct.retrieve( 
{ where: { 
    RecordTypeId: {IN: ['id1','id2']}, 
  }
  limit: 1 
},  

function(err, records) { 
    if (err) { 
        alert(err); 
    } else { 
        console.log(records.length); 
        console.log(records[0]); 
    } 
 } 
);
```

.Every Support process is created as a record in the BusinessProcess Object
.Recordtype has a field called BusinessProcessId

Hence query for necessary support process first from the BusinessProcess object and then query related recordtypes related to the business process

Comment: one support process can be linked to more than one record type.  Each records type is linked to one support process.  That said I think eyal83 is trying to get the case status values that correspond to process A only.

Comment: @gorav: I am trying to get all the case statuses associated with a specific process.

Comment: You will need to query first business process object then record type object and then case records ..hope that helps .

Comment: @mohith I don't believe querying the record type object can get you the status values for the record type.  It looks like querying business process object might do the trick but not familiar w it.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_businessprocess.htm

Comment: You have to query both ..first query business process and then next based on business process query records typeid

Comment: How does that get you to the case status picklist values?

Comment: You need to filter recordtypeIds here ..recordtype object has reference to business process ID..so you get hold of exact case records..

Comment: Let's forget about doing this in a dynamic way for a second. I know the specific record type id and corresponding business process. What's next?

Comment: And a related question, how do I get the possible priority values? (low, medium, high, something else...)